# Sort by array elements

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList<double[]>`

I want to sort the List according to the number in the array in ascending order

first sort by `double[0]`

then by `double[1]`

...

lastly by `double[n-1]` where `n` is the size of the double array

Is there any simple way to do this in Java?

Considered an example of arraylist that have 4 double arrays

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{2,3,4,5,6}
{0,1,2,3,4}
{0,2,2,3,4}
```

After sorting it will be

```
{0,1,2,3,4}
{0,2,2,3,4}//first element(0=0) is the same, it looks at the second element, and 2>1
{1,2,3,4,5}
{2,3,4,5,6}
```

it will first look sort by the first elements, if it is same it will see the second, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` depending on whether your outer collection is an array or a `List`, with a custom comparator:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a,
        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Just write a custom comparator in `double[]`. Given the object oriented-ness of Java, that will be a class you write implementing `Comparator`.

There's a similar solution involving `Comparable`, if you're willing to (you may not be) wrap your `double[]` in some wrapper class `LexicalDouble`, with the specified comparison method.

```
private static class Lexical implements Comparator<double[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < o1.length && i < o2.length; i++) {
            if (o1[i] != o2[i]) {
                return o1[i] - o2[i] > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }

        if (o2.length != o1.length) {
            // how to compare these?
            return o1.length - o2.length;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] a = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, -2 } };
    Arrays.sort(a, new Lexical());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still not very sure with this answer. Is it possible to have some example codes?

Comment: @william007 Example Code ---> http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/182-how-sort-array-using-java-util-arrays-class.html

Comment: Because your starting with an array list you will need to convert it to a primitive array, `double[][] primitiveArray = arrayList.toArray(new double[0][0]);`. The sorted result will be saved in that primitive array. If you want to convert it back you can use `Arrays.asList(primitiveArray)`

Comment: @ns47731 not necessary, can use `Collections.sort`. Edited.

Comment: @djechlin definitely, but as per your example it is necessary. OP states they start from `ArrayList<double[]>`

Answer (score 1):

There is a method you can use:

```
Arrays.sort();
```

Sorts the specified array into ascending numerical order.